# Как сделать анимацию в UITableViewCell фона?

Tags: анимация, objective-c

Есть у меня `Cell` в табличном представлении, и при определенном событии я хочу запустить анимацию бакраунда, но анимация не запускается, а цвет сразу заливается на новый. Кто сталкивался с этим вопросом?

Comment: Странно, у меня работает.

Comment: Покажите код, который вы используете для анимации и код вызова этой анимации.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, необходимо анимированно изменить цвет фона ячейки? 
Если это делать в событии выбора ячейки, то код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                     animations:^{
                         [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
}
```